# How to append form value and DE field value in url?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to add form input value and DE field value in a URL.

I have a cloud page where customer will enter mobile number. I want to add product name in the URL associated with that Mobile number in a DE.

`@Mobile number` and `@ProductName`

The URL format is as below:

`https://xyz.abc.xx.zz/productname?mobile=xxxxx`

I want to replace product name with value availalbe in a DE and xxxx with form input value which is mobile number.

I was able to add mobile numder using concat function, however i'm unable to add product name.

```
Set @FMobile  = RequestParameter("mobile")
set @pageurl = "https://xyz.abc.xx.zz/productname?mobile=xxxxx"
set @pageurl = Concat(@pageurl, "mobile=", @Fmobile)
```

Comment: You need to do a lookup to the DE to get the value

Answer (score 2):

I would do a lookup where the mobile variable is stored, here is a snippet:

```
set @key = [{primary key in DE}]
set @FMobile  = Lookup("{DE_that_stores_value}","{Column_of_which_you_want 
returned}","{Column_you_want_to_lookup_against}", @key)
set @pageurl = "https://xyz.abc.xx.zz/productname"
set @pageurl = Concat(@pageurl, "?mobile=", @Fmobile)
```

If you are trying to look up the product based on the mobile number in the request parameter of a submitted form I would do the lookup on `@ProductName` with the key being the request parameter in your lookup `@key  = RequestParameter("mobile")`

You can read more about the ampscript lookup function here: https://ampscript.guide/lookup/

Comment: Thanks, Nate! It worked.